# How can I improve the alignment of a line on tab press in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I switched from Atom to VSCode. There is one point that is very annoying. Below is an example that prompted me to write a question here.

[image]

That is, pressing tab always inserts 2 spaces and has no understanding of the position of the beginning of the code in the upper line.

In Atom, tab can insert 1 space if required:

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution? This has been bugging me since I started using VSCode.

Comment: @FlorianBlume Have not found. I continue to suffer and put manually one space...

Comment: I´m using Auto-Align extension. It´s great!

Answer (score 0):

First go to the "Show All Commands" tab in VSCode.

Then search for "convert indentation".

Then you can edit your preference for spacing which should solve your problem.

Comment: Try [CTRL] [SHIFT] [P] to bring up the command pallete. Similarly it is under the View tab. Then type 'indentation' in the search box and it should give you a few options.

Comment: This list includes converting to spaces or tabs. I need to insert one space instead of two in my example. I need that by clicking on tab the editor understands that in this place I need not two spaces, but one. Or even so that from the very beginning of the line, the cursor falls into the body of the hash with the required amount of indentation. In other words - I need identical behavior from the Atom editor.

Comment: I added an example from Atom